# My Radio Buttons are not visible on the webpage

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the book "PHP and SQL for dummies 4th edition" to learn web programming. My PetCatalog interface is meant to retrieve and display all petTypes from my Database. It is retrieving the pets in the database but it is doing so without the radio buttons. I do not know where the error is from because everything seems to be in place in the code. 
Note: Everything works perfectly except that the radio buttons symbol are not being displayed. PS: There need to be a fictional database for this program to make any sense to anyone trying to help because the database is in my system. Thanks.

```
<?php
/* Program: PetCatalog.php
* Desc: Displays a list of pet categories from the
* PetType table. Includes descriptions.
* Displays radio buttons for user to check.
*/
?>
<html>
<head><title>Pet Types</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$user="root";
$host="localhost";
$password="";
$database="PetCatalog";
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) 
or die ("couldn't connect to server");
/* Select all categories from PetType table */
$query = "SELECT * FROM PetType ORDER BY petType"; 
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
/* Display text before form */
echo "<div style='margin-left: .1in'>\n
<h1 style='text-align: center'>Pet Catalog</h1>\n
<h2 style='text-align: center'>The following animal
friends are waiting for you.</h2>\n
<p style='text-align: center'>Find just what you want
and hurry in to the store to pick up your
new friend.</p>
<h3>Which pet are you interested in?</h3>\n";
/* Create form containing selection list */
echo "<form action='ShowPets.php' method='POST'>\n";
echo "<table cellpadding='5' border='1'>";
$counter=1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
extract($row);
echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='15%'
style='font-weight: bold;
font-size:1.2em'\n";

echo "<input type='radio' name='interest' value='$petType'\n"; 
if( $counter == 1 )
{
echo "checked='checked'";
}

echo ">$petType</td>"; 
echo "<td>$typeDescription</td></tr>";
$counter++;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Select Pet Type'>
</form></p>\n"; 
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The book should have contained a section about *checking for errors*.

Comment: "View source" in your browser and look for broken markup. Firefox will sometimes highlight it. You can also run it through a markup validator such as the W3C one, though that will probably highlight a lot of issues overall that aren't necessarily related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the fact that your line with

```
echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='15%'
style='font-weight: bold;
font-size:1.2em'\n";
```

does not close the `<td>` tag. This could interfere with the creation of your `<input>` tags.

Try

```
echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='15%'
style='font-weight: bold;
font-size:1.2em'>\n";
```

and see if that works.

Comment: you were quick than me in seconds

Comment: It now works well. God bless you bro. Thank you VERY VERY VERY VERY much. You don't know how much I appreciate this...I have benn battling with it for some days now trying to find the bug.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help! Mind marking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: No problem @Ulabcie! Thank you for my first correct answer! (I'm new to answering questions here.)

Answer (score 0):

Like justathoughtor2 said close the table data and table row `</td></tr>` i have tested your without closing the table data and table row 
[image: no radio buttons]

after closing the table data and table row 
[image]